# Why newff() does not work properly when I use its arguments!

Tags: matlab, neural-network

My data-set includes 29 inputs and 6 outputs. When I use

```
net = newff(minmax(Pl),[14 12 8 6]);
```

to build my feed forward MLP network and train it by

```
net.trainParam.epochs=50;
net=train(net,Pl,Tl);
```

the network can not learn my data-set and its error does not decrease below 0.7, but when I use arguments of newff function like this:

```
net=newff(minmax(Pl),[14 12 8 6],{'tansig' 'tansig' 'tansig' 'purelin'},'trainlm');
```

the error is decreased very fast and it comes below 0.0001! The unusual note is that when I use the previous code using only one layer including 2 neurons:

```
net=newff(minmax(Pl),[2 6],{'tansig' 'purelin'},'trainlm');
```

the error is decreased below 0.2 again and it is doubtful! 
Please give me some tips and help me to know what is difference between:

```
net = newff(minmax(Pl),[14 12 8 6]);
```

and

```
net=newff(minmax(Pl),[14 12 8 myANN.m],{'tansig' 'tansig' 'tansig' 'purelin'},'trainlm');
```

?

Comment: What version of MATLAB are you using? Also, don't use so many hidden layers. You need one, maybe two. Backprop across many layers doesn't work well.

Comment: also what are the dimensions of your input/target data?

Answer (score 0):

I think that the second argument to [NEWFF](http://www.mathworks.com/help/releases/R2010a/toolbox/nnet/newff.html) *(link requires login)* is supposed to be the target vectors, not the size of hidden layers (which is the third argument).

Note that the default transfer function for hidden layers is `tansig` and for output layer is `purelin`, and the default training algorithm is `trainlm`.

Finally, remember that if you want to get reproducible results, you have to manually reset the random number generator to a fixed state at the beginning of each run.

Comment: An older version of `newff` used the calling convention that he is using, so he might have an older version of MATLAB. In some such versions the default trainer was `traingdx` rather than `trainlm`, so specifying that might have some impact.

Comment: @kwatord: thanks for pointing that out (do you know what version exactly? BTW In the latest version, `newff` became deprecated altogether).. The main point is to remember to seed the random number generator the same way before each run, if you want to compare the result of training neural networks.